# How to assign an Excel Range to a 2D array?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Could you please say- how a Excel Range("G2:AA1000") can be assigned to a 2D array? If possible how to return back that 2D array to the same range after performing some operation on that 2D array?After assignment a Range to an 2D array,How each row will be identified from that 2D matrix?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easy way to make changes to an area using an array, and write it out to the same place, or somewhere else.

This example code will copy data from one area to another, using an array:

```
Sub example()
Dim testdata()
testdata = Range("A1:B13")
Range("D1:E13") = testdata ' simple copy
Range("G1") = testdata ' copy only 1 cell
Range("I1:K22") = testdata 'try to copy too much
End Sub
```

The `testdata` array starts from **1**, and will extend to the number of columns and rows specified in the range. In this case, `testdata(1,1)` refers to the data obtained from **A1**, `testdata(1,2)` refers to **B1**, finishing up with `testdata(13,1)` referring to **A13**, and `testdata(13,2)` referring to **B13**.

Setting the range equal to the array in the next line copies the array into the specified location.

- If the area is smaller than the original array, it will copy only enough of the array to fill that space, so `Range("D1")=testdata` will only place one cell on the sheet.
- If you specify a larger area, then **#N/A** will fill the area that is not in the space covered by array elements, so `Range("A1:A3")=testdata` will fill A1 and A2 with data from the array, but A3 will have **#N/A**

Result of example program:
Note: A1:B13 is the original data, which gets copied with the subsequent `range(??)=testdata`
[image: Result of above code]

Comment: nice explanations,but last two points are not much clear. what is `#N/A`?

Comment: **#N/A** is an error produced by excel when there is no information available. see the first definition on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N/a)

Comment: I am not clear still.Any graphical presentation can make sense I think so!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a worked-out example of reading a range of data from a worksheet, operating on the array, and then writing it back out to the same worksheet.

```
    Sub RangeArray()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Arr()
    Dim ArrItem
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rUB as Long, cUB as Long

     Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G19")
    rUB = Rng.Rows.Count    'Row upper bound
    cUB = Rng.Columns.Count  ' Column upper bound

    ReDim Arr(1 To rUB, 1 To cUB)

   'Read worksheet range into array
    For i = 1 To rUB
       For j = 1 to cUB
          Arr(i, j) = Rng.Cells(i, j).Value
       Next
    Next

   'Do something to array 
    For i = 1 To rUB
       For j = 1 To cUB
          If i <> j Then
             Arr(i, j) = Arr(i, j) / (i * j)
          End If
       Next
    Next

   'Write array back to worksheet
    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I1")
    For i = 1 To rUB
       For j = 1 To cUB
          Rng.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value = Arr(i, j)
       Next
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible without loop?

Comment: Actually, yes, @Tukai. Using arrays is an old habit. This will work as well:
    Sub RangeArray()
        Dim A()
        A = Sheet1.Range("A1.G19")
        'do something with array
        Sheet1.Range("i1.i19").Value = A
    End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an Excel range *can* be assigned to a 2D array in one single assignment. In C++/CLI it looks like this:

cli::array<Object^, 2>^ arrData = safe_cast<cli::array<Object^, 2>^>(rg->Value[Excel::XlRangeValueDataType::xlRangeValueDefault]);
In c# or visual  basic it would look considerably simpler (see here for example https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/assign-range-to-array/, btw in dotnet the object is now playing the role of the variant data type). Note that it must be a two dimensional array and the returned array has a one-based indexing, and not a zero based indexing.

For large data sets this method is a lot faster than the looping. The looping generates lots of COM objects. I compared the two methods with a 33000 row Excel range and the data import into the array was almost instantaneous while with the looping it took very long and it heated up the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

One way to loop through a range is to use the For...Next loop with the Cells property. Using the Cells property, you can substitute the loop counter (or other variables or expressions) for the cell index numbers. In the following example, the variable counter is substituted for the row index. The procedure loops through the range C1:C20, setting to 0 (zero) any number whose absolute value is less than 0.01.

```
Sub RoundToZero1()
    For Counter = 1 To 20
        Set curCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 3)
        If Abs(curCell.Value) < 0.01 Then curCell.Value = 0
    Next Counter
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not looking for this! I am looking for an assignment which can be done with a single statement! and the `Range("G2:AA1000")` should be look like this not only a single column!

Comment: why you used that `0.01` value, wanted to know the logic - what the intension is?