# What list type in VBScript allows insertion and deletion of elements?

Tags: list, excel, vbscript, vba

Is there an VBScript Array type class or anything like that,where I can add items between two of its Items? And once added then its existing items should shift to manage the locations. the functionality I am looking for which is available for removal of Items from the `ArrayList or Dictionary objects`,where after removal also the items made them contiguous by their own efforts,we don't need to take care of such things.I am looking for also same Add items between methods if any!

Thanks

Comment: @pst Is it available in VBScript? - that was my question

Comment: Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What a surprise: [ArrayList.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.arraylist.insert%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**Demo v. 2.0:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim alA  : Set alA  = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim alB  : Set alB  = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

alA.Add "A"
alA.Add "C"
alA.Insert 1, "B"

alB.Add "one"
alB.Add "two"

WScript.Echo "alA: ", Join(AlA.ToArray())

alA.InsertRange 1, (alB) ' Call By Value () needed!

WScript.Echo "alA: ", Join(AlA.ToArray())
```

output:

```
alA:  A B C
alA:  A one two B C
```

Comment: ~~~Merry Christmas~~~ Woowwww!! Is it available in VBScript? Ohh My GOD!! Thanks for your time. :-)

Comment: Just can you give a one more example with the `ArrayList.InsertRange Method` method? I am confused with this. Please help!

Comment: Yes! That's the one I was looking for! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you give me quick tips on the post? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035772/how-to-assign-an-excel-range-to-a-2d-array/14036291#14036291